# When did SunOS get a graphical interface?

Tags: unix, gui, sunos, sun-workstation

I understand that the first graphical user interface for SunOS was SunTools (later renamed to SunView), but I cannot find any documentation that states when it was released and for which versions of SunOS it was compatible with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunos, Sun UNIX 0.7 had no windowing system, and SunOS 1.0 (November 1983) introduced the Sun Windowing System.

I think the first Sun machine I used was a 68020 running SunOS 2.0, which definitely had a graphical interface, so the above is at least consistent with my experience.

Comment: I can't remember if it X-Windows based.  X-Windows came out in 1984.  When I first saw the machine in 1987, it had a graphical interface that would lose track of itself every so often and redraw the windows from the bottom most to the topmost.

Comment: SunView and NeWS weren’t X-based; the first Sun windowing system with X was OpenWindows IIRC.

Comment: @StephenKitt - wasn't NeWS the beautiful but somewhat impractical-on-that-hardware GUI that was based on Postscript?

Comment: @davidbak [Display PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_PostScript), what an interesting concept. Too bad it probably came both too early to be run with adequate speed and too late to get any kind of widespread adoption.

Comment: Sun certainly did use X Windows before switching to NeWS.  In 1989 I used a Sun-2 with X Windows and SunView, without NeWS, and two years later I used a Sun Sparc with NeWS.  So yeah, X Windows on Sun was definitely a thing.

Comment: @DrSheldon did Sun *provide* an X server themselves before OpenWindows? AFAIK X10 and X11 were ported to Sun systems by others, I’m wondering whether that was what you used.